# How To Get .txt File Contents JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a file input like this in html

```
<input type='file' id='textin'></input>
```

How Do I Get The Contents Of The .txt File Uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```js
function previewFile() {
  const content = document.querySelector('.content');
  const [file] = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    // this will then display a text file
    content.innerText = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()" id="textin"><br>
<p class="content"></p>
```